# Convert text to date PHP

Tags: php, date

I receive some data, in it I get the date with this format:

`250117` (means 25/01/2017)
`50117` (means 05/01/2017

I didn't find any function that can convert this date using PHP.
Any suggestion will be great. Thanks

Comment: So you completely missed finding [DateTime::createFromformat()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: `$string = '50117';
$dto = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmy', sprintf('%06s', $string));
echo $dto->format('Y-m-d');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$string = '50117';
$dto = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmy', sprintf('%06s', $string));
echo $dto->format('d/m/Y');

?>
```